# jquery passing values between 2 chained forms

Tags: jquery, html

Afternoon all, My question pertains to 2 chained forms, where values from the first form are validated and if OK the 2nd form is shown (and the input fields from the 1st are deactivated and the submit button hidden).

My question is: how can i get values from the first form be attached to the second form as hidden fields.

My code goes like this:

```
<form id="upfotos_dados" action="POST">
     <p class="desc_nome"><strong>O seu nome: </strong></p>
     <input type="text" id="fotos_nome" />

     <p class="desc_email"><strong>O seu email: </strong></p>
     <input type="text" id="fotos_email" />

     <p class="desc_especie"><strong>Fotografias da espécie: </strong></p>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="fotos_especie" value="Asplenium Cetarach" disabled />

     <input value="Confirmar" type="submit" name="submit" class="button submit_dados" />
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>

<form id="upload_imagens" action="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload')">
  <div id="queue"></div>
  <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple>
  <input value="Enviar Fotografias" type="submit" name="submit" class="enviafotos-button" /> 
</form>
```

And the jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#upload_imagens").hide();    
    });

    $('.submit_dados').live("click",function(){

        if($('#fotos_email').val() == ''){ $('#fotos_email').parent().find('.desc_email').append("<span style='color:#A00'>Campo obrigatório.</span>"); return false; }
        else if(!IsEmail($('#fotos_email').val()) ){ $('#fotos_email').parent().find('.desc_email').append("<span style='color:#A00'>Email incorrecto.</span>"); return false; }
        if($('#fotos_nome').val() == ''){ $('#fotos_nome').parent().find('.desc_nome').append("<span style='color:#A00'>Campo obrigatório.</span>"); return false; }
        if($('#fotos_especie').val() == ''){ $('#fotos_especie').parent().find('.desc_especie').append("<span style='color:#A00'>Campo obrigatório.</span>"); return false; }

        if($('#fotos_email').val() != '' && IsEmail($('#fotos_email').val()) && $('#fotos_nome').val() != '' && $('#fotos_especie').val() != ''){
            $("#upload_dados").hide();
            $("#upload_imagens").show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Some things are still work in progress, like simultaneous validation of the fields that unfortunatelly I haven't manage to do it right yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know the reason you have to have two separate forms instead of one, one possible approach is looping through all inputs of first form and append them as children to the second form.. Something like this:

```
$('#form1 input, #form1 select').each(function(index, element){
  $(#form2).append('<input type="hidden" name="'+$(element).attr('id')+'" value="'+$(element).val()+'">');
});
```

Something like that, maybe that is what you're looking for?

Comment: The thing is the second form is the fields to upload pictures using uploadify and that is hard to customise :| that's why I went with 2 forms instead of one, so I can force people to fill the data first and only then they are able to upload pictures.

Answer (score 1):

This should take all inputs from upfotos_dados and append hidden inputs in upload_imagens for each of them with the id -> name and value -> value

```
$("#upfotos_dados input").each(function() {
    $(#upload_imagens).append('<input type="hidden" name="'+this.id+'" value="'+this.value+'">');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your .submit_dados click event handler. with some refactor code like, and append input values from `upload_dados` to hidden fields in `upload_imagens`.

And you dont need to check values again while appending these values, because you have already done these validations.

```
$('.submit_dados').on("click", function () {
    var parent =$("#upload_dados");
    var fotos_email = $('#fotos_email');
    var fotos_email_value = fotos_email.val();
    var fotos_nome = $('#fotos_nome');
    var fotos_nome_value = fotos_nome.val();
    var fotos_especie = $('#fotos_especie');
    var fotos_especie_value = fotos_especie.val();

    if (fotos_email_value == '') { parent.find('.desc_email').append("<span style='color:#A00'>Campo obrigatório.</span>"); return false; }
    else if (!IsEmail(fotos_email_value)) { parent.find('.desc_email').append("<span style='color:#A00'>Email incorrecto.</span>"); return false; }
    if (fotos_nome_value == '') { parent.find('.desc_nome').append("<span style='color:#A00'>Campo obrigatório.</span>"); return false; }
    if (fotos_especie_value == '') { parent.find('.desc_especie').append("<span style='color:#A00'>Campo obrigatório.</span>"); return false; }

    //if (fotos_email_value != '' && IsEmail(fotos_email_value) && fotos_nome_value != '' && fotos_especie_value.val() != '') {
    //var upload_dados = $("#upload_dados");
    parent.hide();
    var upload_imagens = $("#upload_imagens");

    parent.find('input').each(function () {
        upload_imagens.append($('<input/>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', this.id).val(this.value));
    });
    return false;
    //}
});
```